# Filter products by variants' tags

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, filter

I want to set up a product filter system based on variants' tags. I encounter two difficulties.

**1. Outputting all variants' tags from a group of products.**

```
<!-- Relation does not work -->
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type('Custom').find() %}
{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants.relatedTo(products) %} 

{% for pattern in craft.tags.group('patternSwatch').relatedTo(variants) %}
    <a href="?pattern={{ pattern.name | url_encode }}">{{ pattern.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<!-- This works but returns tags from ALL products' variants -->
{% for pattern in craft.tags.group('patternSwatch').relatedTo(craft.commerce.variants) %}
    <a href="?pattern={{ pattern.name | url_encode }}">{{ pattern.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**2. Filter product based on the multiple variants' tags**

```
<!-- This works, but what about filtering by multiple tags? -->
{% set pattern = craft.request.getParam('pattern') %}
{% set tag = craft.tags.group('patternSwatch').title(pattern).first() %}
{% set variants = craft.commerce.variants.relatedTo(tag) %}

{% for v in variants %}
    {{ v.product.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use categories for a 'facetted search' filter you describe, as categories are less likely to get out of control. e.g. If tags are seldom re-used then a search for a tag may only produce a single result.

This plugin may help you: https://github.com/iainurquhart/FacetedNav_CraftPlugin

If you're going to use tags then I suggest making use of Craft's search functionality as this will allow you to submit the tag as a search term and **also display any entries which contain the word/tag in ANY field** of the entries within Craft.